# Performance: typedef vs wrapper class for primitive types?

Tags: c++, inline, micro-optimization

I want to define a new type in C++ which is just some primitive type (in my example an `int`, could be any type). I call the type `NodeId` in this example.

I could just use `typedef int NodeId`. I want a default value for `NodeId`s, so I would use `#define NULL_NODE_ID -1`.

Now, I think it would be nicer to define a class instead of `typedef` to allow a function `isValid()` and a default constructor constructing a null `NodeId`:

```
class NodeId
{
    int value;
public:
    inline NodeId() : value(-1) {}
    inline NodeId(int value) : value(value) {}
    inline operator int() {return value;}
    inline bool isValid() {return value != -1;}
    //...
};
```

Are there any performance disadvantages which result in using the second method?

Comment: If you use a new compiler, then that should be the same as using the int.

Comment: @mfontanini Then why did you downvote the question? This is answer to the question, you should post it as such.

Comment: @leemes why are you assuming it was me?

Comment: @mfontanini Ok sorry, was two seconds after your comment. If it wasn't you, just ignore me. But you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: Unrelated: `const NodeId NullNodeId = -1;` is better than the `#define`.

Comment: You probably also want `explicit` on the constructor.

Comment: no, I don't want explicit on the constructor, as I want the class to behave as much as a basic type as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there are two reasons this could conceivably be slower.

First, there's no way to create an uninitialized NodeId. Normally, that's a *good* thing. But imagine you have code like this:

```
NodeId nodeid;
foo.initializeNodeId(&nodeid);
```

You'll be doing an extra assignment which isn't actually necessary.

You can fix that by adding a special constructor. It's probably much better to create a Foo::createNodeId() so you don't need Foo::initializeNodeId(&NodeId), but if you don't control the definition of Foo, that may not be possible.

Second, a NodeId is not a compile-time constant expression. As dasblinkenlight suggests, this is far more likely to cause problems with code not being legal than to cause performance problems, but both are possible. (Why? Because you may be forcing the compiler to insert code to do some calculation at runtime that could have been done at compile time, if you were using an int. Not that this is likely to be an issue for a class called NodeId…)

Fortunately, if you're using C++11, you can fix that with constexpr. And if you want your code to also be legal C++03, you can deal with that with a macro.

Also, as pointed out by dasblinkenlight, you're missing const in two methods.

Finally, there's no reason to write "inline" on methods that are defined inside the class definition; they're already inherently inline.

Putting it all together:

```
#if __cplusplus > 201000L
#define CONSTEXPR_ constexpr
#else
#define CONSTEXPR_
#endif

class NodeId
{
    int value;
public:
    struct Uninitialized {};
    CONSTEXPR_ NodeId() : value(-1) {}
    CONSTEXPR_ NodeId(Uninitialized) {}      
    CONSTEXPR_ NodeId(int value) : value(value) {}
    CONSTEXPR_ operator int() const {return value;}
    CONSTEXPR_ bool isValid() const {return value != -1;}
    //...
};
```

Now you can do this, to avoid the cost of an extra -1 assignment.

```
NodeId nodeId(NodeId::Uninitialized());
foo.initializeNodeId(&nodeid);
```

And this, to legally use a NodeId as a non-type template parameter:

```
myClassTemplate<NodeId(3)> c;
```

Or, this, to be sure the compiler can legally just initialize x to 4:

```
int x = 3;
x += NodeId(1);
```

Comment: abarnert, is there a possibility to support integer arithmetic out of the box? `NodeId node; node++;` doesn't compile. I have to implement the `operator++` manually. Is this possible without manually implementing those trivial operators?

Comment: @leemes: No, not completely automatically. But boost.operator can help you define some explicitly and get others for free. If you're doing lots of these classes, you can use CRTP, a base class, or a code generator so at least you only have to define all the operators once. Or define a single "SmartInt" class template, and then do something like "struct NodeIdTag{}; typedef SmartInt<NodeIdTag,-1> NodeId;" (which of course you can wrap up in a macro).

Comment: @abarnert I found a really simple way to support all arithmetic operators out of the box: Just define another `operator int&()` :)

Comment: @leemes: Try defining two different int-wrapper classes with operator int& and try out all the combinations of arithmetic. But combining that with a inheritance/CRTP/tagged-template trick might be enough?

Answer (score 4):

If you use a relatively new compiler, then the generated code should be the same. The compiler should have no problem inlining those member functions. In case you really have doubts about it, you can always disassemble the executable.

Comment: That's not quite true. `int` is a POD type, but `NodeId` is not. The compiler will generate extra initialization code where this is used, you're forbidden from using it in unions, and it will 'infect' other classes with its non-PODness.

Comment: `NodeId x;` should produce the same code as "int x(-1);", since that is the way OP would use that type if it were an `int`. The non-POD argument is true though.

Comment: @DanHulme C++11 [allows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Unrestricted_unions) non-aggregates in unions

Comment: @Prætorian That's true. I tend to assume the question is not about C++11 unless it is tagged [tag:c++11] or it says so explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

If the compiler optimization settings let the compiler inline everything, there should be no performance differences. The only disadvantage that I can spot is that expressions based on objects of this class may no longer qualify as compile-time constants, which may be important in template programming. Other than that, you end up with additional clarity at no runtime cost.

---

P.S. You are missing `const` in your `operator int` and `isValid`:

```
inline operator int() const {return value;}
inline bool isValid() const {return value != -1;}
```

Comment: "compile-time *constant expressions*", perhaps?

Comment: you are right about the const, I just hacked this example to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on making this into a library that may get used by some other programming language (like if you are writing this into a C++ DLL) there are definite advantages to having it a `typedef int`.

For example, when you are writing a python wrapper or a java wrapper for your API, you don't have as much headache getting your class and types to port over.  Then all you have to worry about is the bit size of the `int`.